# GCP k8 times out not sure how to open the ports

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a simple api I am trying to use in GCP to get the hang of it. I create a pod then a service with a load balancer but I can't hit an external endpoint IP am I missing a step?

Added A firewall rule as well

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-sample-api-lb --allow=tcp:31000
```

Pod Config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "sample-api-lx"
  labels:
    app: sample-api-lx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: sample-api-lx
      image: {image}     
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 0.2
          memory: "365Mi"
```

Service Config

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "sample-api-lx"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: "sample-api-lx"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80 
      nodePort: 31000
```

DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

Comment: What request are you trying to make, what result exactly are you seeing? You should find out the external IP of the service you created and try to connect to it on port 80.

Comment: that's what I try I get the external IP then append the port and api/values and it times out

Comment: When you do `kubectl describe pod sample-api-lx` does it show that it’s Ready?

Comment: it does everything looks good

Comment: Do i need like a healthcheck endpoint registered?

Comment: I created a new GCP project, a new GKE cluster with standard settings (except only 1 node instead of 3, and only 2GB for the node instead of the default 3.75GB or whatever it is), and created a pod and service exactly like yours, using `nginx` in place of `{image}`, and am able to reach it fine on `<EXTERNAL_IP>:80` where `<EXTERNAL_IP>` is the external IP of the LB that was created. I didn't need to create any firewall rules, you shouldn't have to do that either.  Are you sure you're trying the right IP and port (80)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I upgraded to 1.13.7-gke.24 and it works now. Never mind that was a red haring here was the real issue https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/19010

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Pod is in the Ready state (which you can see via `kubectl describe pod sample-api-lx`), you should be able to connect to your app **without** adding an additional firewall rule. To connect to the Load Balancer, you need to use the `port`, not the `nodePort`. Specifically, find the External IP of the Load Balancer (which you can see via `kubectl get service sample-api-lb`) and `curl <EXTERNAL_IP>` or go to `<EXTERNAL_IP>` in your browser.

On GCP specifically, you can go to the console, navigate to your cluster, and click the link on the sidebar for Services.  You should see a link to `<EXTERNAL_IP>:80` there and when you click on it, it will do the same as above, i.e. opening the address in your browser.

I reproduced this with the following steps:

1. created a new GCP project
2. created a new GKE cluster with default settings, except it only had 1 node instead of 3, and the worker node had 2GB instead of the default 3.75GB, just to save money
3. created a Pod just like yours, replacing `{image}` with `nginx`
4. created a Service just like yours
5. Successfully `curl`ed it, and viewed it in my browser by clicking the link of the Service as shown in the GCP console

If it still doesn't work, the Kubernetes docs provide [guidelines for troubleshooting Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/).

Comment: so that is exactly what I am doing but my image is a basic .net core web api does that make a difference?

Comment: Could you go through this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/. Try those steps, which doesn't work as expected to narrow down your root cause?

Comment: Thanks ill take a look